# After using nltk download to get the corpora, I still can not import the corporas

Tags: python

**My code**

I use the following code in Colab

```
import nltk
nltk.download('reuters')

from nltk.corpus import reuters
files = reuters.fileids()
print(files)
```

**The result**

The result shows it has already download the package reuters, but can't find it.

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [nltk_data] Downloading package reuters to /root/nltk_data...
> LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
>      79             except LookupError as e:
> ---> 80                 try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
>      81                 except LookupError: raise e
>
> 5 frames
> LookupError: 
> **********************************************************************
>   Resource reuters not found.
>   Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
>
>   >>> import nltk
>   >>> nltk.download('reuters')
>   
>   Searched in:
>     - '/root/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
> **********************************************************************
> ```

Comment: "Corpora" is the Latin plural of the singular "corpus".

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Copy-pasted your code, worked fine. Can you specify versions you're using? Python + nltk

Answer (score 0):

To run in colab, you need to decompress the file and add a line of code.

```
!unzip -o /root/nltk_data/corpora/reuters.zip -d /root/nltk_data/corpora/
```

before using the corpus